# Rails: extra db queries occurring on a has_one relationship

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, associations

I'm building a rails app, in which I have models: Team, Player, Team_Player, and many statistical models belonging to Player. The model Team_Player acts as an in-between connecting Teams and Players.

My question is this: when I call something like

```
player = Player.find(team_player.player_id),
```

rails makes quite a number of database calls, not only to the Player model, but also to the statistical models associated with Player. I understand that the rails default behavior is not to load associated models, unless I specify it. Thus, I'm assuming that I've specified this behavior somewhere. However, I'm honestly not sure where/how I've done that. I realize that this is a strange question, but given the below, any idea why all the extra database calls are being made?

Here's how I've related my models (with an example statistical model):

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :team_players
end

class TeamPlayer < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :team
    belongs_to :player 
end


class Player < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :team_players
    has_one :passing_stats_season_total, dependent: :destroy

    delegate *PassingStatsSeasonTotal::ATTR_METHODS, to: :passing_stats_season_total

    after_initialize do
        self.build_passing_stats_season_total if passing_stats_season_total.nil?
    end 
end

class PassingStatsSeasonTotal < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :player

    ATTR_METHODS = [:attempts, :attempts=, etc.]
end
```

And now the view where I actually make the database call:

```
<tbody>
    <% @team.team_players.each do |team_player| %>
        <tr>
            <% player = Player.find(team_player.player_id) %>
            <td><%= player.name %></td>
            etc.
        </tr>
    <% end %>
</tbody>
```

Here's the console output:

```
aPlayer = team.team_players.first
  TeamPlayer Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "team_players".* FROM "team_players" WHERE "team_players"."team_id" = ? ORDER BY "team_players"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["team_id", 132], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<TeamPlayer id: 1114, player_id: 8373, team_id: 132, created_at: "2016-12-30 00:11:42", updated_at: "2016-12-30 00:11:42"> 

player = Player.find(aPlayer.player_id)
  Player Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "players".* FROM "players" WHERE "players"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 8373], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  PassingStatsSeasonTotal Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "passing_stats_season_totals".* FROM "passing_stats_season_totals" WHERE "passing_stats_season_totals"."player_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["player_id", 8373], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<Player id: # and a bunch of other stuff>
```

In this example, how come the model PassingStatsSeasonTotal was also loaded?
I realize this is a strange question, but any help would be really appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: I think its something related to the `after_initialize` block.

Comment: Alright, I'll try getting rid of that block, and then create the models elsewhere, when I need them.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the help

Comment: When I got rid of the after initialize statement, it worked properly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conditional in this line loads the `PassingStatsSeasonTotal` association:

```
self.build_passing_stats_season_total if passing_stats_season_total.nil?
```

The reason is that `passing_stats_season_total` is a reference to the association. Before any methods can be called on it, Rails needs to load it.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thank you1

Answer (score 0):

My own answer: I deleted the after_initialize block, and simply created a statistical model elsewhere, when I needed it. I'm not really sure why the after_initialize block changed the default behavior, but that's what happened.